# Font Awesome icons not showing using Ruby Gem

Tags: css, ruby, fonts, rubygems, font-awesome

I'm using Font-awesome via the ruby gem (ruby-2.2.2, font-awesome-sass-4.3.2) and the font icons look fine locally, but are broken when viewed remotely or when deployed on a server.

I have followed the instructions [laid out here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) but when I look at my compiled CSS the expected unicode numbers have been replaced by boxes:

```
.fa-glass:before {
  content: "";
}
```

instead of

```
.fa-glass:before {
  content: "\f000";
}
```

I have already tried including `@charset "UTF-8";` at the top of my SASS file which imports font-awesome.

Ideas anyone?

---

**Edit: 17/06/15**

[I've raised this issue with Font-awesome themselves.](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/6773#issuecomment-112882602) Hopefully they'll shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that the escaped chars are replaced with unescaped chars in the CSS.

The problem is that the font file hasn't loaded and that is why you see black boxes instead of the correct glyphs.

When looking at the CSS sent to the browser from your example site that you linked from Font-Awesomes github I can see invalid urls for the font.

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url(font-path("font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot"));
```

This means that the scss hasn't been properly parsed in your application.

Comment: This is strange, because I followed the instructions. It's just a ruby gem.

Comment: How exactly do you include font-awesome into the asset pipeline?

Comment: I followed the sass install (gem). Top of my main sass file I include them `@import 'font-awesome-sprockets'; @import 'font-awesome';` and in my config.rb file `require 'font-awesome-sass'`.